# PHP How to split variables from an array into two columns of checkboxes?

Tags: php, html

This is what I have so far and it prints out my contents into one column. The data is coming from a DB. I would like to split it into two columns since its a long list. Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you.

```
foreach($buildings as $b) {
 $bldgChecked = '';
 if(in_array($b, $selected_buildings)) $bldgChecked = 'CHECKED';
    echo "<div class='form-check'>
    <input class='form-check-input checkitem' type='checkbox' name='building[]' $bldgChecked value='$b' />$b</br>
    </div>";
  }
```

[image: Current Output]

Comment: What do you mean split into two columns? What is your current output and what would your desired output look like?

Comment: @RenéBeneš I just added how my output looks right now. Since I have about about 50 items in this array right now, I'd like to print the checkboxes into two columns. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the array `$buildings` into chunks using `array_chunk` and process each chunk as you are here. Byrendering into two distinct `div` ( or other element ) you can style as appropriate to get layout you need. Alternatively this could have been accomplished, more or less, with css.

```
$chunks=array_chunk($buildings,count($buildings)/2);

foreach( $chunks as $buildings ){

    echo "<div>";

    foreach($buildings as $b) {
        $bldgChecked = '';
        if( in_array( $b, $selected_buildings ) ) $bldgChecked = 'CHECKED';

        echo "
        <div class='form-check'>
            <input class='form-check-input checkitem' type='checkbox' name='building[]' $bldgChecked value='$b' />$b</br>
        </div>";
    }

    echo "</div>";
}
```

example:

```
<?php
    $buildings=array(
        'aaa','sco','wat','erd','faf','ghm','bsb',
        'cct','fjl','ppo','kln','rln','bqa','pmt',
        'xes','oil','gym','rob','sci','wwc','soc',
        'maw','ton','xxr','tit', 'yle','fud','csw'
    );
    $chunks=array_chunk( $buildings, count($buildings)/2 );
    $selected_buildings=array('ppo','xxr','ghm','bsb');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .col{width:10rem;clear:none;display:inline-block;padding:1rem;margin:1rem;border:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.1)}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            foreach( $chunks as $buildings ){

                echo "<div class='col'>";

                foreach($buildings as $b) {
                    $bldgChecked = '';
                    if( in_array( $b, $selected_buildings ) ) $bldgChecked = 'CHECKED';

                    echo "
                    <div class='form-check'>
                        <input class='form-check-input checkitem' type='checkbox' name='building[]' $bldgChecked value='$b' />$b</br>
                    </div>";
                }

                echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Hmm...That seems to give me the same output.

Comment: ok - it'll need a tweak or two but now it is processing in distinct blocks

Answer (score 0):

For two column output, you need to apply a bit of styling (CSS). Normally you would separate the content from the logic, but to convey the general idea I've put all the code in one script.

```
<?php
$buildings = ['ah', 'atg', 'ats', 'bsb', 'ccc', 'cns', 'cs', 'csw', 'fa', 'gym', 'law', 'rob', 'sci', 'soc', 'wrt', 'wwc',];
$selected_buildings = ['cs', 'law',];
foreach($buildings as $b) {
    $bldgChecked = '';
    if(in_array($b, $selected_buildings)) $bldgChecked = 'CHECKED';
    $output[] = "<div class='form-check'>
    <input class='form-check-input checkitem' type='checkbox' name='building[]' $bldgChecked value='$b' />$b</br>
    </div>";
}
$count = count($output);
$right = floor($count/2); // split in two
$left = $count - $right; // left column length always >= right column

/* build two column html */
$lCol = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $left; $i++) {
    $lCol .= $output[$i];
}
$rCol = '';
for($i = $left; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $rCol .= $output[$i];
}

// define CSS for two columns
$style = <<<HEREDOC
<style>
    #lCol {
      width: 100px;
      float: left;
    }
    #rCol {
      margin-left: 100px; /* match width of left column */
    }
    .clear {
    clear: both;
}
  </style>
HEREDOC;
echo $style; // output CSS
?>

<html>
    <body>
    <div id="twoCols">
        <div id="lCol">
            <?= $lCol; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="rCol">
            <?= $rCol; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Bootstrap` then use `col-md-6` like below

```
echo "<div class='form-check col-md-6'>
    <input class='form-check-input checkitem' type='checkbox' name='building[]' $bldgChecked value='$b' />$b</br>
    </div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $chunks as $buildings ){
foreach($buildings as $b) {
    $bldgChecked = '';
    if( in_array( $b, $selected_buildings ) ) $bldgChecked = 'CHECKED';
        $selected = explode(',', $b);
        $choise1= $selected[0];
        $choise1 = $selected[1];
```

Possible that function can help you.